# how to use the sqlite query to retrieve the data that i need from three table?

Tags: android, select, runtime-error, android-sqlite, nul

i have android application that use the sqlite database pre populated  the problem is that i need to make a select query from 3 tables  where the first table

**venue**

- _id
- name
- city

**team**

- _id
- group_id
- code
- name

**match**

- _id
- stage
- venue_id
- team1_id
- team2_id
- kickoff

what i need is to make a select query that have the **name from venue**,  **kickoff from match**, **name from team** and **name from team**

**where the first name is the first team and the second name is the second team**

## this is my query :

```
select v.name,m.[kickoff],t.name,stage
from venue v,match m,team t
where m.venue_id = v._id
and 
t._id = m.team1_id
and 
t._id = m.team2_id
```

Comment: Is there a problem with the query you posted or are you asking how to run the query?

Comment: no there is a mistake in my query  i think in the last line and i am asking if there is any other solution to get what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query should be what you are after:

```
SELECT v.Name, m.[kickoff], team1.name, team2.name, stage
    FROM Match AS m
    INNER JOIN Venue AS V ON m.venue_id = v._id
    INNER JOIN Team AS team1 ON m.team1_id = team1._id
    INNER JOIN Team AS team2 ON m.team2_id = team2._id
```

I think the problem that are having with your original query is that there are actually 2 teams linked to a match but you are only accounting for one, and the last part of your query:

```
t._id = m.team1_id
and 
t._id = m.team2_id
```

... will only be true if the team is playing itself.

Comment: so i will make 2 tables team1 and team2 to get my result thank you

Comment: You can have just one table - Teams - and join it into the query twice. Notice that the in the example the actual table name is the same but I give each one an alias.

Comment: how to join the team table twice and get the result without having the  same error **will only be true if the team is playing itself.**

Comment: As in my example, one of the teams table joins in on Match.team1_id and the other is joined in Match.team2_id. In this way you join 2 teams, each joined on a different foreign key in match.